# C program convert Char Instructions into String Instructions from text file

Tags: c, string, math, line, operation

My input text file looks like this currently

```
a 5 
a 10
s 8
r
```

the result is= 49 (5+10-8*2)

But it should look like this:

```
ADD 5 
ADD 10
SUB 10
SQR
```

My question is, how do I convert the char instructions into string instructions?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

FILE *fp;
char buff[255];
char numBuff[10];

int a;
int val = 0;
int len;

fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");


while(fgets(buff, 255, fp) != NULL){
  len = strlen(buff);
  strncpy (numBuff, buff+2, len-2);
  numBuff[len-2] = '\0';

  a = atoi(numBuff);

// Char Operations
  if(buff[0] == 's'){       //Subtract
      val -= a;
  }else if(buff[0]=='a'){   //Add
      val += a;
  }else if(buff[0]=='m'){  //Multiplicate
      val *= a;
  }else if(buff[0]=='d'){  // Divide
      val /= a;
  }else if(buff[0]=='r'){  //Power*2
      val = pow(val,2);
  }

}

printf("%d \n",val);
return 0;


}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad formatting, this is my first question here!

Comment: Just research about how to read, tokenise,, and compare strings: `strcmp()`, etc.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Do you mean that in addition to reading the input file and performing the calculation, you want to write to an output file with the ADD/SUB/SQR format? Or do you mean that you want to modify your code so that it can read an input file in the ADD/SUB/SQR format instead of an input file in the a/s/r format?

Comment: @Stef I think OP asks how to read multiple characters instead of a single character, so e.g. `"ADD"` instead of `'a'`

Comment: @Sted I mean exactly like gkhaos describes. I tried for hours but I simply cannot make it work with strcmp( )

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` is the solution. But you have to compare the right things.

First get the operation written in the file:

```
strcpy(operation, buff, 3);
```

Then you can use it in strcmp. Even better, use strncmp:

```
if(strncmp(operation, "ADD", 3) == 0)
{
    // Do things
}
```

So in you code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

FILE *fp;
char buff[255];
char numBuff[10];
char operation[3];

int a;
int val = 0;
int len;

fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");


while(fgets(buff, 255, fp) != NULL){
  len = strlen(buff);
  strncpy (numBuff, buff+2, len-2);
  numBuff[len-2] = '\0';

  // Get the operation
  strcpy(operation, buff, 3);

  a = atoi(numBuff);

// Char Operations
  if(strncmp(operation, "SUB", 3) == 0){       //Subtract
      val -= a;
  }else if(strncmp(operation, "ADD", 3) == 0){   //Add
      val += a;
  }else if(strncmp(operation, "MUL", 3) == 0){  //Multiplicate
      val *= a;
  }else if(strncmp(operation, "DIV", 3) == 0){  // Divide
      val /= a;
  }else if(strncmp(operation, "SQR", 3) == 0){  //Power*2
      val = pow(val,2);
  }

}

printf("%d \n",val);
return 0;


}
```